# Autocomplete PHP with Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

so I have a global.php which creates a couple of variables, for example:

```
$tpl = new Smarty();
```

When trying to autocomplete from `$tpl->` in index.php, I don't get any suggestions. Autocompleting within global.php works fine, but it's obviously useless if it only works in the file the variable is created in.

Any setting to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I've had almost a similar problem, I think the reason in my case was because I didn't create a new PHP Project and I just created .php files. I created a PHP Project in NetBeans and I just added my old files and it autocomplete worked just fine.

Comment: I did in fact create the PHP project from within Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a doc block:

```
// this should be in the file youre working on in, not necessarily 
// in the file where the variable is defined

require_once 'global.php';

/*
 * @var $tpl Smarty
 */

// work with $tpl here
```

Also AFIK completion is not picked up from outside files like if you do an include unless its a function or a class definition because those get scanned. However thats normally not a problem because if you are using NB or Eclipse becuase youre probably working in an OOP way which means youd have vary little of this occurrence :-)

Comment: The PHP doc part did not work. I'm only using classes and functions, but autocomplete from other files does not work. Funny enough, the variable names will be autocompleted, it just does not work for any methods, both static and non-static.

Comment: Righy but if you create the variable in a file other than the one youre working in then you have to tell it what you expect variable to be because it doesnt auto scan all the vars from included files so far as i know. Which leads me to an issue with my answer... in order for what i posted to work you need the docblock in the file youre working on to "import" the variable. Not sure if that will work still but thats the only way i could think of doing it. Then agian i use Eclipse+PDT 99% of the time.

Comment: That didn't help either unfortunately... I might look into PDT.

Answer (score 0):

Create

```
$tpl = new Smarty()
```

in your index.php during editing the .php file. Autocomplete will work. When you are done, just comment the line above out so you are not overwritting the object when executing the script.